# LoadLibrary failure when loading x64\mip_file_sdk.dll

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to run a release version of my MIP SDK integration after recently upgrading to the latest version of the SDK. I can run my service without any issue when running in the Visual Studio debugger. However, when I install the release version as a Windows service, I receive an error:

LoadLibrary failed for: [C:\Program Files\LinkDocuments\x64\mip_file_sdk.dll]    at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.SafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary(String dllToLoad)
at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls(String dllFolder, String dllName, String[] dllDependencies)
at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize(MipComponent mipComponent, String path)

I am not sure how to debug this issue? Any advice is helpful.

The service is built for an x64 target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Visual C++ runtime installed?

Comment: Tom - yes - Visual C++ 2015-2022 redistributable runtime is installed. Version 14.31.31103.0

Comment: I used dumpbin and checked that all of these dependencies are present: 
    libgsf-1-114.dll
    libgobject-2.0-0.dll
    libglib-2.0-0.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    RPCRT4.dll
    MSVCP140.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    VCRUNTIME140_1.dll

Comment: While Visual C++ runtime was not specifically the problem, it was a DLL problem. My installer did not use the right version of libpcre, which changed with this update.